# How can I toggle those two divs while clicking on an inside div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have:

**HTML CODE:**

```
<div id="katy"> 

<div> 
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="a"> Button 1 </a>
</div>

</div>

<div id="perry"> 

<div>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" style="display:none;" id="b"> Button 2 </a>
</div>

</div>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[Button 1](http://example.com)

**WHAT I WANT:**

You click on [Button 1](http://example.com), it will show [Button 2](http://example.com).
You click on [Button 2](http://example.com), it will show [Button 1](http://example.com).

How can I toggle those two divs while clicking on an inside div?

Comment: Your jsfiddle links are broken.

Comment: I just linked anything to demonstrate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier for you if you move the `display:none` part to the `div` instead of link.

```
<div id="katy"> <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="a"> Button 1 </a> </div>
<div id="perry" style="display:none;"> <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="b"> Button 2 </a></div>
```

Then you can use this jQuery code:

```
$('#a').click(function(){
    toggle();
});

$('#b').click(function(){
    toggle();
});

function toggle(){
    $('#katy').toggle();
    $('#perry').toggle();   
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K5Va3/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Add a click handler and toggle/show/hide the other button.

Example Javascript:

```
var button1 = $('#a'),
    button2 = $('#b');

var toggle = function() {
    button1.toggle();
    button2.toggle();
};

button1.click(toggle);
button2.click(toggle);
```

[Working jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/aWLMX/)

Answer (score 0):

Just create a `<script></script>` and handle the click with JavaScript like this:

```
var a = document.getElementById("a"),
    b = document.getElementById("b");

a.onclick = function() {
    this.style.display = "inline";
    b.style.display = "none";
}

b.onclick = function() {
    this.style.display = "inline";
    a.style.display = "none";
}
```